# How do you properly setup pyssh (PYTHON)

Tags: python

I'm trying to test out pyssh, but I'm having trouble importing it.
I'm new to python so I'm not sure how to get this thing to import properly.

What do I have to do before I can import pyssh 0.3 into my code?

Comment: What trouble are you having? What have you tried, what errors do you get?

Comment: I always receive the error "ImportError: No module named pyssh". I'm just confused as to what I have to do before hand in order to import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Python to import a module, it has to be either in the `PYTHONPATH`, or in the current directory. You can check this by looking at `sys.path`.

Check the [documentation on modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

Comment: Thanks, I am able to import it now. However I am receiving a syntax error within the pyssh code...

Comment: @Takkun: You should post this as another question. If you do, include the exact error you get, as well as you Python version and platform.